# AudioPlayers does not work on iOS | Flutter plugin

Tags: ios, flutter, file, audio, flutter-audioplayers

I am creating a Flutter plugin. Currently, the code:

1. Synthesises an String into an audio file
2. Gets the path to the file
3. Plays the audio file using [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

When I run the application in Android, it perfectly works. Nevertheless, when I run it on iOS, it does not (assuming relates permissions/restrictions)

```
await flutterTts
        .synthesizeToFile(
            "This is my first audio synthesizer in Flutter", audioFileName)
        .then((success) => {
              if (success == 1)
                {
                  print('Successfully synthesized!!'),

                  // Gets the path to the generated file depending on the platform
                  pathFile =
                      Platform.isAndroid ? pathToFileAndroid : pathToFileIos,
                  pathFile
                      .then((pathToAudioFile) => {
                            print('Path to file: ' + pathToAudioFile),
                            // Speakers/earpiece
                            // int result = await player.earpieceOrSpeakersToggle();
                            // Sets the path to the file
                            audioPlayer.setUrl(pathToAudioFile),
                            audioPlayer.setVolume(1.0),
                            // Gets the duration of the audio file to be reproduced
                            // Plays the audio file
                            playLocal(audioPlayer, pathToAudioFile),
                          }) // pathFile
                      .catchError((e) {
                    print('Error: Unable to get the path to the audio file');
                  }),
                }, // success
            }) //synthesizeToFile
        .catchError((e) {
      print('Error during the synthesisation: $e');
    });
  }




/// Gets the path to the file to be accessed (iOS)
  static Future<String> get pathToFileIos async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    print('appDocPath: $appDocPath');
    return '$appDocPath/$audioFileName';
  }
```

I implemented `audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen` to confirm that the path to the file is the correct one (it actually gets the duration of the file). Nevertheless, the file is not played.

I am using a simulator to test the application, and this is the path where the file is stored

> /localPaty/Devices/deviceID/data/Containers/Data/Application/appID/Documents/temp_audio_cue.caf

I read different questions regarding this topic, but I did not find a solution for my case

I have tried:

Editing Transport security as the documentation recommends

```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Using `AudioCache` ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800637/flutter-audio-player-play-sound-not-working-in-ios))

Anyone has any other suggestion? Do I need to move the file to my local assets and use `AudioCache` to reproduce the file?

**Update**

I have also tried to add the flag `isLocal`.

```
  playLocal() async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(localPath, isLocal: true);
  }
```

According to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) is is needed cause

> The isLocal flag is required only because iOS and macOS make a difference about it

It returns `1`, so I guess that it means success, but the sound is still not triggered. Could be the simulator failing?

```
"iOS => call startHeadlessService, playerId ID"
"iOS => call setUrl, playerId ID"
"iOS => call setVolume, playerId ID"
"iOS => call play, playerId ID"
2021-02-03 11:59:33.149925+0100 Runner[61496:850044] flutter: Played successfully?: 1
```

I have also tested to call `playLocal()` with a wrong path. It keeps returning `1` but after it it displays the following error:

> FigFileForkOpenMainByCFURL signalled err=2 (errno) (open failed)

Nevertheless, the error is not triggered with calling the method with the correct `localPath` so I assume it should be playing it correctly.

**Note**

If instead of calling `playLocal()`, I call `flutter_tts.speak('test')`, it works. Therefore, the error should probably be related to `audioplayers`.

The versions that I am using are `flutter_tts ^2.1.0` and `audioplayers: ^0.17.3`

Comment: hello i've a question where i've to add these in flutter app.

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
final AudioContext audioContext = AudioContext(
    iOS: AudioContextIOS(
      defaultToSpeaker: true,
      category: AVAudioSessionCategory.ambient,
      options: [
        AVAudioSessionOptions.defaultToSpeaker,
        AVAudioSessionOptions.mixWithOthers,
      ],
    ),
    android: AudioContextAndroid(
      isSpeakerphoneOn: true,
      stayAwake: true,
      contentType: AndroidContentType.sonification,
      usageType: AndroidUsageType.assistanceSonification,
      audioFocus: AndroidAudioFocus.none,
    ),
  );
  AudioPlayer.global.setGlobalAudioContext(audioContext);
```

Add this in you main.dart file before this runApp(App());

Comment: Not sure why this isn't standard in the `audio_players` default. My android was working fine, but the iPhone14 Pro Max was giving out the sound through the earpiece, almost inaudible. Copy-pasting the code above gave me a bunch of errors, but after I changed a few options to the code it worked.

Comment: here are my updates to the above code:           `iOS: AudioContextIOS(
        defaultToSpeaker: true,
        category: AVAudioSessionCategory.playback,
        options: [
          AVAudioSessionOptions.defaultToSpeaker,
          AVAudioSessionOptions.mixWithOthers,
        ],
      ),
      android: AudioContextAndroid(
        isSpeakerphoneOn: true,
        stayAwake: true,
        contentType: AndroidContentType.music,
        usageType: AndroidUsageType.assistanceSonification,
        audioFocus: AndroidAudioFocus.gain,
      ),`

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I realised that the problem was related to `AVAudioSession` and its session management. Both libraries, `flutter_tts` and `audioplayers` make use of it and therefore they could overlay it other.

I had to change the method to the following:

```
 /// Synthesises the current audio cue into an audio file
  static Future<void> synthesiseStringToAudioFile() async {
    int synthesized = await flutterTts.synthesizeToFile(
        "This is my first audio synthesizer in Flutter", audioFileName);
    if (synthesized == 1) {
      String pathFile =
          await (Platform.isAndroid ? pathToFileAndroid : pathToFileIos);
      print('Path to file: ' + pathFile);
      playAudioFile(pathFile);
    } else {
      print('Error during the synthesisation');
    }
  }
```

to start triggering some audio in `iOS`. Still, there are some problems within the notifications, but I consider that the answer has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

When you play sounds with [**audio players**](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) and use [**flutter_tts**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts) to say words, it makes flutter_tts dysfunctional on iOS

Thus, only one of the package works, but as soon as both are used at the same time, tts stops working after a while. Sometimes it lasts longer, but sometimes it stops immediately.

> In reality ,this is due to a conflict on the iOS side.

Assuming it works on Android, that means there shouldn't be a problem in your code.

Another alternative would have to be found .

Answer (score 0):

Today I've fixed this way. I was using audio from the URL and I was using this line

```
  var res = await audioPlayer.play(url, isLocal: true);
```

I've to use this below line into my code

```
  var res = await audioPlayer.play(url, isLocal: false);
```

`isLocal` stands for your file is stored locally or not. if the file is stored remotely which means in the form of URL then set to `isLocal:false`.

hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use play() method instead of playBytes() while working with IOS. int result=0; if(Platform.isIOS){ result = await player.play("Audio url",isLocal: false); }